# Map a Keyboard shortcut to some other keyboard shortcut with Python

Tags: python, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Basically, I want to make something similar to `Karabiner Elements`, but in Python for MacOS. I want to know if it's possible to listen for some keyboard shortcut, prevent it from sending, then push out my own shortcut instead. However, the only thing I could find is for listening for keyboard shortcuts only on the same console as the python program is running, no globally on the system.

Answer (score 0):

(Tested on GNU/Linux)This will listen globally on the system, but I don't know if it will prevent the shortcut from sending:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl + shift + z', print, args=('Shortcut detected',))

keyboard.wait('esc')
```

Comment: On MacOS, it runs for a few seconds, then exits.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example for Mapping Select All, Copy, paste to F1,F2,F3 button respectively

```
import keyboard
keyboard.remap_hotkey('F1', 'ctrl+a')
keyboard.remap_hotkey('F2', 'ctrl+c')
keyboard.remap_hotkey('F3', 'ctrl+v')

while True:
    keyboard.wait()
```